# Trying to make a cogs loader discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So basically I was trying to make a cogs loder from a youtube toutorial(https://youtu.be/vQw8cFfZPx0)but i am getting some error and i dont know how to fix it. I am using anaconda navigator virtual environment in vscode. My anaconda navigator virtual environment name is disc
This is my file

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= "#")

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
 client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
 client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")

@client.command
async def reload(ctx, extension):
 client.reload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}") 

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
 if filename.endswith('.py'):
     client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
       
client.run('token')
```

Here is my cogs file

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Example(commands.cog):
    
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("bot is online")

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("pong")      



def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Example(client))
```

This is my terminal

```
PS C:\Users\Oindrieel\Desktop\bot> conda activate disc
PS C:\Users\Oindrieel\Desktop\bot> & C:/Users/Oindrieel/anaconda3/envs/disc/python.exe c:/Users/Oindrieel/Desktop/bot/bot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Oindrieel\anaconda3\envs\disc\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 606, in _load_from_module_spec
    spec.loader.exec_module(lib)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Oindrieel\Desktop\bot\bot.py", line 21, in <module>
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
  File "C:\Users\Oindrieel\anaconda3\envs\disc\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 678, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\Oindrieel\anaconda3\envs\disc\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 609, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.example' raised an error: TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
PS C:\Users\Oindrieel\Desktop\bot>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in cogs file is all correct just a simple error. Just change the `class Example(commands.cog):` to `class Example(commands.Cog):` where c in Cog is capital. Just change this your code starts to work